# ReportViewer control works in development environment but not in IIS 6.0 

Tags: iis-6, reportviewer

I have a page with a ReportViewer control that works on my development machine (vs2008) but not in IIS 6.0.  What do I need to change in my web.config or in IIS 6.0 to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [Microsoft Report Viewer 2008 SP1 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=BB196D5D-76C2-4A0E-9458-267D22B6AAC6&displaylang=en) on the new server.